# Spark: String manipulation to ColumnA to ColumnB

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

Hi I'm new to spark and I wanted to know how I can do string manipulation so Column1 - Column2 to get column3.

Note: My data is in data frame

So basically I have two different column string and I wanted to get only the string that is existed in column2 but not in column 1 to I can produce it as column3

```
Column1
SAMPLE_OUT_3_APPLE|BANANA|GUAVA|ORANGE

Column2
SAMPLE_OUT_3_APPLE|BANANA|GUAVA|GRAPES|ORANGE|BERRY
```

Then Column3 should be...

```
Column3
GRAPES,BERRY
```

but for column1 and column2 I also wanted to show

```
APPLE,BANANA,ORANGE
```

Just removing the `SAMPLE_OUT_3` and doing having comma delimited

Comment: can you share the schema of dataframe ?

Comment: @koiralo
  |-- column1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column2: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 1):

you can split your column by '|' like below
import spark.implicits._

```
val df = mainDf.select("Column1","Column2").map(x => {
   val s1 = x.getAsString(0).replaceAll("^.*3_","").split("|");
   val s2 = x.getAsString(1).replaceAll("^.*3_","").split("|");
   (x.getAsString(0),x.getAsString(1),s2.diff(s1).union(s1.diff(s2)))
}
).toDF("Column1","Column2","Column3")
```

Comment: SAMPLE_OUT_3_ in the first can be different but it always have 3 _

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve your purpose through regexp_replace and udf.

1. regexp_replace to replace "|" with "," and ".*3_" with ""
2. udf to get the value of column3 from column2 and column1

```
val df1 = Seq(("SAMPLE_OUT_3_APPLE|BANANA|GUAVA|ORANGE" ,"SAMPLE_OUT_3_APPLE|BANANA|GUAVA|GRAPES|ORANGE|BERRY")).toDF("column1","column2")           
val df2 =df1.columns.foldLeft(df) { (memoDF, colName) =>
            memoDF.withColumn(
            colName,
            regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col(colName), "\\|", ","),".*3_",""))}

val diff_udf = udf { ( a:  String, b:  String) => (a.split(",") diff b.split(",")).mkString(",") }

df2.withColumn("column3", diff_udf(col("column2"), col("column1"))).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
|column1                  |column2                               |column3     |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
|APPLE,BANANA,GUAVA,ORANGE|APPLE,BANANA,GUAVA,GRAPES,ORANGE,BERRY|GRAPES,BERRY|
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Spark >= 2.4**

You can use `array_except`

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("SAMPLE_OUT_3_APPLE|BANANA|GUAVA|ORANGE" ,"SAMPLE_OUT_3_APPLE|BANANA|GUAVA|GRAPES|ORANGE|BERRY")
).toDF("column1", "column2")

val remove = df.columns.map(column => split(col(column), "3_").getItem(1).as(column))

val resultDF = df.select(remove: _*)
  .withColumn("column1", split($"column1", "\\|"))
  .withColumn("column2", split($"column2", "\\|"))
  .withColumn("column3", array_except($"column2", $"column1"))
  .withColumn("column1", array_except($"column1", $"column3"))
  .withColumn("column2", array_except($"column2", $"column3"))

val convertToString = resultDF.columns.map(column => concat_ws("|", col(column)).as(column))
resultDF.select(convertToString: _*).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
|column1                  |column2                  |column3     |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
|APPLE|BANANA|GUAVA|ORANGE|APPLE|BANANA|GUAVA|ORANGE|GRAPES|BERRY|
+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: how can I bring it back to string? And for column 1 and 2 I wanted to format it to something like APPLE,BANANA,GUAVA,GRAPES,ORANGEBERRY